# global variables not working in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces, global

The simple question is how do namespaces affect global variables?read the rest for more info
I have a working website in php.All the link addresses are made using get queries.(e.g:example.com/?page=contact instead of example.com/contact.php).i have overriden the super global variables in my symfony controller and configured the route.so that works.
my problem is with the global variables.there is a main index.php file which i have included in my controller (indexController) and that has all the code for the website.but the global variables don't work anymore(they've disappeared).i figured that was because of controller namespace but in the php documents it states that namespaces don't affect variables.so what could the problem be?the index.php would generate the expected results if run seperately but here i get undeclared variables)
 this would be my code:index.php creates $html with HTML data

```
namespace example\exampleBundle\Controller

class indexController{
    function indexAction(Request $request){
        $request->overrideGlobals();
        include "/external/index.php";

        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent($html);
        $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type','text/html');
        return $response;
    }
}


------------------------
symfonytest:
     path: /
     defaults: {_controller: exampleexampleBundle:index:index}
```

Comment: Do you use Twig templates? Please show how you make your links, in your router and your template.

Comment: I don't get it. Why are you using Symfony when all of your business logic resides in external/index.php anyway?

Comment: @pierre: i completely agree but the company i work at has decided to move it's resources to the symfony framework.

Comment: @n.1: i get errors before it makes it to the template i will put up the router code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the reason.since the library is included inside a function(indexaction) it is not declared in the global scope.I must use the global modifier inside the included index.php. I will report the results of that.